# Process exited with error code 1

Tags: protractor

Why test run fails in below case using protractor

conf.js

```
    exports.config = {
    framework: 'jasmine',
    seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
    specs: ['example_spec.js']
    }

    example_spec.js

    describe('LoginGUI App Test', function() {
    it('LogInToGUI', function() {
    browser.get('http://10.2.5.6:2772/#/login');
    browser.waitForAngular();
    element(by.model('user.username').sendkeys('abc@gmail.com'));
    element(by.model('user.password').sendkeys('abc123'));
    });
    });
```

Error: 
Process exited with error code 1 
 I have used both sendkeys and sendKeys methods to send values for the keys but the same error seen....not sure why the error seen

Comment: Failures:
                1) LoginGUI App Test LogInToGUI
                  Message:
                    Failed: by.model(...).sendkeys is not a function
                  Stack:
                    TypeError: by.model(...).sendkeys is not a function,

Comment: Error
                        at Suite.<anonymous> (E:\AutomationDevelopment\Protractor_UIAutomation_CloudGUI\example_spec.js:3:3)
                        at Object.<anonymous> (E:\AutomationDevelopment\Protractor_UIAutomation_CloudGUI\example_spec.js:2:1)
                        at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
                        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
                        at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
                        at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)

Answer (score 3):

You are missing a parenthesis after your element declaration, need to close it.

```
element(by.model('user.username')).sendKeys('123');
```

Answer (score 0):

you have a typo in your code.
This should work

```
element(by.model('user.username')).sendKeys('abc@gmail.com');
element(by.model('user.password')).sendKeys('abc123');
```